# Get list of transactions for order

Tags: magento2, transaction

I am developing for magento 2. I have an instance of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and I want to get a list of all of the transactions associated with the order.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

This is a not good answer, you can follow the @adjco answer. Try to use Service Contract.

Try to inject `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory` into your constructor:

```
protected $transactions;

public function __constructor(
  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory $transactions,
  ......
)
{
  $this->transactions = $transactions;
}
```

In your method:

```
$transactions = $this->transactions->create()->addOrderIdFilter($orderId);
$transactions->getItems();
```

If `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory` doesn't work, try to use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Transaction\CollectionFactory`. I'm not test yet both of them.

Comment: I have just tried each of the options you suggest and found that neither works. if I call `$transactions->getTotalCount()` I get `0` for all orders, even those that have associated transactions.

Comment: Ah, I was using the order increment ID, not the order entity ID. I now get the transactions I expected.

Comment: How you get by using the order increment Id?

Comment: No, it _didn't_ work with the _increment_ ID, it _did_ work with the _entity_ ID

Comment: Note: use `$transactions->getItems()` to get a list of transaction object from this.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your class needing the transaction list inject the following (and assign them to appropriate class properties):

`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\Repository`, `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` and `\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder`

Then use the following code to retrieve all transactions for that order and its associated payment:

```
    $filters[] = $this->filterBuilder->setField('payment_id')
        ->setValue($yourOrder->getPayment()->getId())
        ->create();

    $filters[] = $this->filterBuilder->setField('order_id')
        ->setValue($yourOrder->getId())
        ->create();

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters)
        ->create();

    $transactionList = $this->transactionRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

Comment: Can you explain your filters[] approach more?